# How can I get the value out of this "while read" loop in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

So I have this loop

```
    largest=0
    find $path -type f |  while read line; do
            largest=$(stat -c '%s' $line)
    done | sort -nr | head -1
    echo $largest
```

but the variable gets reset after the loop because of the bash subshell thing.

Is there a simple fix I could use to get this variable out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [assign a value to a variable in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275596/assign-a-value-to-a-variable-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
largest=`find $path -type f |  while read line; do
        stat -c '%s' $line
done | sort -nr | head -1`
echo $largest
```

Comment: Wow, such a simple fix. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code in the question is that the `while` loop result runs in a subshell by virtue of the fact that it’s part of a pipeline command. Then, when the subshell exits the value of `largest` is lost.

Since you’re using GNU/Linux (with GNU `find`), you can use its `-printf` option to greatly simplify your command and avoid the unnecessary process forks (to run `stat`) – and the inefficiency of the while loop.

```
find $path -type f -printf "%s\n"  | sort -nr | head -1
```